# Why is my firebase function not reading my algolia keys from runtime config?

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I keep getting the current error when trying to test my firebase function.

```
Found .runtimeconfig.json but the JSON format is invalid.
!  TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Web Dev Stuff\SEEKIO\seekio\functions\index.js:4:56)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at initializeRuntime (C:\Users\msi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:680:29)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
!  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
```

My runtime config looks like this:
[image]
When I delete the config file and run `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json` it just gives me back these variables and the same file format, so I am a bit confused.

My function looks like this:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const algoliasearch = require("algoliasearch");
const client = algoliasearch(
  functions.config().algolia.app,
  functions.config().algolia.key
);
const index = client.initIndex("listings");

exports.createRecord = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .database.ref("/listings/{listingID}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    return index.saveObject({
      objectID: snap.id,
      ...snap.data(),
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you call this command using Powershell:

```
firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json
```

The file `.runtimeconfig.json` is created using `UCS-2 LE BOM` encoding (which won't be read correctly by Node using the default settings).

Instead use this command that uses PowerShell piping:

```
firebase functions:config:get | sc .runtimeconfig.json
```

Now `.runtimeconfig.json` will use the expected plain `UTF-8` encoding.

**Note:** `sc` is the shorthand for the [`Set-Content` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7.1) - which writes a file with the given contents (replacing the file if necessary). `ac` (the [`Add-Content` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.1)) is similar, but is used to append content to a file.

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much, had no idea about this!

Comment: It's also covered in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_functions_configuration_optional).

Comment: The command in the docs for PS is different to this one, and doesn't work for me. But this does.